# Image steganography!

Tags: files, terminal, images

I was solving a steganography challenge - When I typed

```
file image.jpg
```

into the terminal, the result was

```
JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.00, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, comment: "JPEG Encoder Copyright 1998, James R. Weeks and BioElectroMech.", baseline, precision 8, 3840x2160, frames 3`
```

I want to know is what is the significance of the comment

```
"JPEG Encoder Copyright 1998, James R. Weeks and BioElectroMech."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest it is because of [this](https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/mvnforum-1.0.0-rc4_04-src/myvietnam/src/net/myvietnam/mvncore/thirdparty/JpegEncoder.java.shtml) code and the copyright terms which seem to be attached [landserf](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/%7Ejwo/landserf/landserf180/thirdParties/jpegencoder/license.txt) project somehow.

Looks like image you are looking at was probably encoded with that copyrighted code (or a development of it) which which embeds the copyright comment in the metadata

```
public JpegInfo(Image image)
    {
        Components = new float[NumberOfComponents][][];
        compWidth = new int[NumberOfComponents];
        compHeight = new int[NumberOfComponents];
        BlockWidth = new int[NumberOfComponents];
        BlockHeight = new int[NumberOfComponents];
        imageobj = image;
        imageWidth = image.getWidth(null);
        imageHeight = image.getHeight(null);
        Comment = "JPEG Encoder Copyright 1998, James R. Weeks and BioElectroMech.  ";
        getYCCArray();
    }
```

**A little more research**

Here is a comment that may be of interest, from [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326415236_Content-independent_steganography_and_steganalysis_of_JPEG_images) paper on steganography

*Suspicious COM comment Open  source  JPEG  encoders  available  on  the  internet usually add a specific comment to the JPEG file in the  COM marker segment. A number of images with the same comment that are not from a common photo editor software, can be an indication of steganography. **For  example, the JPEG encoder used  for  implementing  the  well-known  F5  steganography algorithm,  always  adds  the  following  comment:  "JPEG Encoder  Copyright  1998,  James  R.  Weeks  and BioElectroMech"***

So bottom line, those images were encoded using the F5 algorithm ...or **were they spoofed!?!?!?!?**

Comment: Thanks of letting me know!

Comment: Was only a web search away!! But I learned a bit too so.... teamwork

Answer (score 1):

The JPEG file format allows for inserting a text comment.  This is a specific field called `COM` in the JPEG file format (see [the Syntax and structure" section in the Wikipedia JPEG article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure), for example).

This comment can be any text. The comment in the image file that you're investigating may have been inserted by the program that encoded the image.